# Reverting multiple edits at once on Wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

If I make a series of edits on Wikipedia that I decide to revert, is it possible to revert multiple edits at once?

The edits are spread across multiple articles.

Comment: Might be better to go to the source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Help_desk

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

1. go to the history tab
2. select the range of revisions you want to revert
3. click Compare selected revisions
4. click the undo link on the second revision
5. make sure this the edit that you want to make and save the page

Comment: I'd like to revert all the recent changes that I've made across the entire wiki (in case I had recently re-categorized several pages incorrectly.)

Answer (score 2):

You can revert multiple edits at once if they are multiple edits to the same article.

But you wanted to revert multiple edits you have made across several different articles. There's no feature of the website to let you do that. There are some quite sophisticated [anti-vandalism tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCleaning_up_vandalism/Tools) which may help. Some of these are desktop applications you'd need to install, others run as javascript in the browser. Some require administrator permissions. I'm not sure which one would serve this purpose best (anyone?)

Another trick to do these things just a little faster than normal, is to use your browsers **tabbed browsing** feature.

- Click on 'my contributions' to see all the edits you want to revert.
- Open each of them with the 'diff' link, in a separate tab. You can do this *very quickly* by holding down ctrl while clicking each link (keyboard shortcuts may vary).
- Now move along each of the tabs you've opened clicking 'undo' and 'save'.

Comment: What I'm really asking is whether it's possible for a user to roll back all of their own edits from a certain point onward. (e. g., starting at one edit, and then automatically reverting all of that user's subsequent edits as well).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go the history tab
2. Click the "edit" link for the revision **before** your changes
3. Save the revision. You'll receive a warning that this will undo multiple changes.

Please do be sure to put in a comment explaining what you're doing.

Comment: I'm referring to all of the changes that I've recently made across the entire wiki, not on just one page.

Comment: Then no, there isn't. There might be a tool available to Administrators, but not to individual users.